Why is the layer cake representation true
Like the title of the question, I am having a lot of trouble convincing myself of the layer cake representation. For clarity, let's use the following article as reference.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation
In it's "proof", I am convinced of the two observation :
$\mathbb{1}_{L(f,t)}(x) = \mathbb{1}_{[0,f(x)]}(t)$ and $f(x) = \int_0^{f(x)}\ 1\ d(t)$.
But whats next ?
From context there seem to be a simple logical leap that I have to make here ?
Any help or insights is appreciated.
Cheers

Hint: Use Fubini.
